# App refactoring from RC4 to release (Component and NgModule)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Question about the changes related to the @Component and @NgModule.

To summarize, correct me if I'm wrong, the point is that Component's directives are now NgModule's declarations.

Ok I get the point, do modules. But I am not sure how to refactor my app..

**The app initially was like that:**

- Main app.ts (with the AppComponent)
- Functional area 1

  - Sub functional area 11

    - List view (Component)
    - Detail view (Component)
  - Sub functional area 12

    - List view (Component)
    - Detail view (Component)
- ... about 4 areas having each 3 sub area
- Technical component directory

  - Technical/UI component 1 (Component)
  - Technical/UI component 2 (Component)
  - ... about 6

**Concretely I think I have two options:**

- Create a NgModule for each of my Component (list/detail view) except the tech one.
- Or create a main NgModule that declares all the dependencies

The first one is adding tons of lines only to declare most of the time a module with on component, seems wrong.
Second case seems bad design, to have all deps at the same place..

**Any advice on what I should do ?** I am not sure that the module's vision fits my app..

Comment: Had same problem week ago. I just created one main module (app.module.ts). At start I though same as you, "is a bad idea", but now I can see that re/build time is much shorter after upgrade, what else my module looks not that bad at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular2 docs recommend [feature modules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules). From the website:

> A feature module delivers a cohesive set of functionality focused on an application business domain, a user workflow, a facility (forms, http, routing), or a collection of related utilities.

Applying this idea to your app, I would put the related 'technical UI components' and 'functional areas' together instead of separating them. Then you'll have multiple modules created for their intent instead of their technical make-up. You'll still need one root module that will import the feature modules.

The goal of the separate modules is to have something that could be, if you wanted to, taken out as-is and plugged directly into another app.

Example layout:

```
- app.module.ts
- app.component.ts
- feature1/
--- feature1.module.ts
--- feature1.component.ts
--- feature1.service.ts
- feature2/
--- feature2.module.ts
--- feature2.directive.ts
--- feature2.component.ts
--- feature2-subcomp/
------ feature2-subcomp.component.ts
------ feature2-subcomp.component.html
```

Of course, each feature module can have as many components/services/directives as you want to meet the requirements of each feature area.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a `NgModule` for each component.
Why don't you create a `NgModule` for each Functional area?
And maybe for each Sub functional areas?

And you only have to import those first-level functional area `NgModule`s to your AppModule.

And don't mind on all that Components inside those `NgModule`s.

That's the point about `NgModule`.. Inside your AppModule you dont want to take care of all sub-components and sub-sub-sub-sub-sub...-sub-components.. :)